# Atom package command from another package

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

Let's say in my custom Atom package I insert a JSON string into a file.
After that, I'd like to run the `beautify-language-json` from `atom-beautify` package automatically.

How can I launch this command from my package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the API documentation, you can use the [`dispatch()`](https://flight-manual.atom.io/api/v1.45.0/CommandRegistry/#instance-dispatch) method for that.

**Example:**

```js
// Example - you *might* want to use a different target
const target = atom.views.getView(atom.workspace);
const commandName = 'atom-beautify:beautify-language-json';

atom.commands.dispatch(target, commandName);
```

Comment: I suppose if you use `atom.workspace` view as a target, it may dispatch command to all opened tabs.
So I used
`const editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor(); const target = editor.element`